# How to create session using jquery in asp.net

Tags: jquery, session, using

How to create session using Jquery in asp.net?

Answer (score 4):

A session is initiated on the serverside. Therefor you will need to make a request, basically making any request to a webservice method or other server generated page will do the trick for you.

You could just send an ajax request to a webservice method (make sure it has enabled Session state). Unless your user has blocked cookies it will work.

If he has blocked cookies, you need him to take a route via an aspx or similair where you initiate the session and set the session parameter in the uri query. Asp.net would probably solve that for you if you look around a bit..

Comment: Thanks for your explanation Stefan. But it is hard for me to understand if you didn't attach source code. Could you attach the example of source code?

Comment: @Momos Parapat feel free to contact me via my website (contact) if you want me to give a tender.